# Changing a users groups

Tags: 2011, core-service

I am trying to alter a user's group memberships using the Tridion Core Service.
I have a UserData object, so I can get their current GroupMemberships.

I am having trouble adding GroupMemberships to the user's account. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could you perhaps provide more information as to what did you tried? what worked? what didn't? errors, stack traces, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You basically need to add/remove a `GroupMemebershipData` to your user's `GroupMemberships[]` data array. Then save user data.

I tried the following code on my T2013 instance and it adds a group membership to the current user (`client` is an instance of `SessionAwareCoreServiceClient`):

```
UserData user = client.GetCurrentUser();
List<GroupMembershipData> groups = new List<GroupMembershipData>(user.GroupMemberships);
GroupMembershipData newGroup = new GroupMembershipData() {
    Group = new LinkToGroupData() {
        IdRef = "tcm:0-10-65568"
    }
};

groups.Add(newGroup);
user.GroupMemberships = groups.ToArray();

client.Save(user, readOptions);
```