# User creation using core service on Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013, core-service, c#

I am trying to automate few daily tasks for some of Tridion admins. We have 800+ publications 600+ users and more than 1000 groups. So, I am trying to automate user creation. Recently we have migrated from 2009 version, where I used COM+ to achieve this, but that code is not working anymore on 2013. I want to use core service, hence would be great if some sample project is available. I am using C# (4.0 framework).

Comment: Have you evaluated the option to migrate the users and groups from 2009 to 2013?

Comment: The migration of exiting users are already done. What I am asking is for new user creation.

Answer (score 1):

My [blog post on Setting Rights and Permissions](https://blog.indivirtual.nl/set-rights-permissions-using-sdl-tridion-core-service-api/) has example code in Powershell which includes creating users and adding groups to them. It should be straightforward enough to implement similar logic in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about user creation that isn't covered already by synchronization with Active Directory and other such features available out-of-the-box.

To create a user using the Core Service is fairly straight-forward. It involves these steps:

1. Create a new `SessionAwareCoreServiceClient`.
2. Call `GetDefaultData` on the client and pass in `ItemType.User` as the first parameter. This will give you a UserData object with all of the default data filled in.
3. Set the properties you care about, such as `Title`, `Description`, `Privileges`, etc.
4. Save the user by calling `Create` on the client and passing in the user object.

The only sample code I have for this is the [Tridion PowerShell Modules](https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules) project I wrote. Perhaps it is still useful for you? If so, have a look at the New-User function in [Trustees.ps1](https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules/blob/master/Trustees.psm1). You could even use these modules to automate it, if you know how to use PowerShell.

Also, be sure to download the [Core Service API documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF) from the 2013 SP1 documentation.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks a lot. I am not very comfortable at using Powershell. I have a website built in the same location where Tridion CMS is hosted. So basically the main URL is same, but I am using a different location to host my website. I have a list of AD accounts who can use it but I also want to impersonate all activities via one account already in CMS as ADMIN.

Comment: Hi Peter, I saw the powershell implementation and tried to use it in C#. I am having few problems. The major problem is how I can set up the new user to be added to a group and then set the publication scope. The GroupMembershipData object has Group and Scope both. Group is of LinkToGroupData object type, where I can define two main stuff, an Id Ref (TCM ID), a Title. At the moment I am unable set them as the way powershell code is done in C#. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I would have to see the code to know what is going wrong. But have a look at the following answer: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/2995/141

If you still cannot get it to work, perhaps you could ask a new question specific to how you add group memberships to users/groups? And include the code you wrote so we can help troubleshoot it.

Comment: Excellent!! I was looking for this.. Many many many thanks Peter

Comment: You're most welcome! Glad to hear it helped you out :)

Comment: Peter, I tried to use the article: tridion.stackexchange.com/a/2995/141 and facing a typical issue. I am trying to get a list of all users using:
obj = client.GetSystemWideList(new UsersFilterData());, but I am not getting GroupMembershipData for any of these users as part of UserData. Is this normal? What can I do to fetch groupMembership details of a single user? I thought I could use the following:
List<GroupMembershipData> groups = new List<GroupMembershipData>(user.GroupMemberships); where 'user' is the UserData object.
Can you please point me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you get a list of items, it doesn't load all of the data for those items (since that would be a lot slower). So in this case, you'll need to loop over the list of users and load each user in term. Then the group memberships will be loaded.