# How to get groups members in sdl tridion using core service in c#

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion, content-manager, c#

I trying to get the group members from cms. I have tried this code it gives all users how to get the group members. I want to get the members from the admin group I know the tcm id tcm:0-2570-61168

```
                   var users = basicClient.GetSystemWideList(new UsersFilterData {
                BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.IdAndTitle, IsPredefined = false });
```

also tried this code

```
var targetType = basicClient.Read("tcm:0-2570-61168", readoptions);
```

the above code returns the groupdata object with no any getmembers method

**I want to get all members from a given group and remove specific user from that given group**

Comment: Check https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/2995/33 and if it works, make sure to add reply to your own question with your solution, so it can help others!